# CakePHP: The Code was working perfectly but just start bringing this error

Tags: sql, cakephp, group-by

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'app.Tasks.task_completed' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
>
> If you are using SQL keywords as table column names, you can enable identifier quoting for your database connection in config/app.php.
>
> SQL Query:
>
> ```sql
> SELECT
>     COUNT(TasksEmployees.task_id) AS `count`,
>     TasksEmployees.employee_id AS `employee_id`,
>     Tasks.task_completed AS `task_completed` 
> FROM
>     tasks_employees TasksEmployees 
>     LEFT JOIN tasks Tasks ON (
>         Tasks.task_completed = :c0 AND
>         Tasks.id = (TasksEmployees.task_id)
>     ) 
> WHERE
>     YEAR(TasksEmployees.created) = :c1 
> GROUP BY
>     TasksEmployees.employee_id
> ```
>
> If you want to customize this error message, create src/Template/Error/pdo_error.ctp

Comment: Please do not only post an error message, this is not helpful. All one can pretty much do here is tell you what you could already easily find with a basic google search for the error message. If you need more specific help with your CakePHP code, you should post the code relevant to the error, explain what it is that you don't understand about it, and please also always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 options to resolve this:

1 - If you have sql root access and permissions (it could be from phpmyadmin), so remove `only_full_group_by` from `sql_mode` var

[image]

Click in edit and remove that var.

2 - Include all fields selected in `SELECT` clause into the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
    SELECT
    COUNT(TasksEmployees.task_id) AS `count`,
    TasksEmployees.employee_id AS `employee_id`,
    Tasks.task_completed AS `task_completed` 
    FROM
    tasks_employees TasksEmployees 
    LEFT JOIN tasks Tasks ON (
        Tasks.task_completed = :c0 AND
        Tasks.id = (TasksEmployees.task_id)
    ) 
WHERE
    YEAR(TasksEmployees.created) = :c1 
GROUP BY
    employee_id, count, task_completed
```

Comment: trying to edit variable but after saving it the only_full_group_by is still showing, is not deleting, what can i do

Comment: @ibiyemioluyemi What do you mean with `only_full_group_by is still showing`? It is still showing the error or you could not remove the variable from sql_mode.

The only way you couldnt delete it is if you dont have permissions to do it, but in this case...you should receive an error message about it.

Did you try with option 2?

Comment: i also try option two, but not working, and how can i get permission to the option one, the Application is Cloud based host, is hosted on Digital Ocean